# Camerax Java Get Available Sizes

Tags: java, android-camerax

How to get all available sizes for the preview in CameraX in Java? I've seen the answer for Kotlin but couldn't make it with Java.

```
val camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview, imageAnalyzer)
val cameraId = Camera2CameraInfo.extractCameraId(camera.cameraInfo)
val cameraManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
val characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId)
val streamConfigurationMap = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)
val outputSizes = streamConfigurationMap.getOutputSizes(format)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is:

```
CameraCharacteristics characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
StreamConfigurationMap streamConfigurationMap = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
int[] outputFormats = streamConfigurationMap.getOutputFormats();
  for (int i = 0; i < outputFormats.length; i++) {
    Size[] outputSizes = streamConfigurationMap.getOutputSizes(outputFormats[i]);
    Log.i("CAMERA_ID", "Sizes for id: " + outputFormats[i]);
    for (int j = 0; j < outputSizes.length; j++) {
      double curr_rel = (double) outputSizes[j].getWidth() / (double) outputSizes[j].getHeight();
      Log.i("CAMERA_ID", "output size: " + outputSizes[j] + "; k = " + curr_rel);
    }
}
```